# What's the difference between cross-fetch and isomorphic-fetch?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch, es6-promise

`cross-fetch` is recommended by the Redux docs while `isomorphic-fetch` is recommended pretty much everywhere else. What's the difference between them?

Comment: `cross-fetch` is a [ponyfill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ponyfill) module, while `isomorphic-fetch` is a polyfill module, at least based on a brief glance at their usage at the top of their respective README files. Otherwise, they're two completely different implementations of the exact same [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) [specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/). Ideally they should work no differently, other than the difference mentioned above.

Answer (score 9):

[isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) hasn't been maintained lately. The last npm update was 4 years ago, and as of now, it has 58 open issues on GitHub.

[cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch) was updated 4 months ago and has one open issue.